# Godot Engine published app gets security alert after adding AdMob

Tags: android, admob, game-engine, android-security, godot

I recently released a simple game made with Godot Engine and after adding the Google AdMob library to display ads, I get this security alert :

[image: Security alert regarding URL credentials]

> Your app contains URL credentials, which is often unintentional.
> Please see this Google Help Center article for more information.

The [link](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7026406) that Google Help provides me is not useful at all.

The library I used to display the ads is bbAdmob ( https://github.com/teamblubee/bbAdmob ).

I just wanted to know if someone has figured out a way to get rid of this problem, or if someone could guide me on how to know which credentials are being filtered, as I suppose they are just my banner pub id and my interstitial pub id of my app.

Cheers!

Comment: code please....